# replace http in phpmyadmin database to https

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to replace in all http in database with https
Using below code in phpmyadmin but showing syntax error, can anyone guide how to do.

**Code**

> UPDATE `mytable_rsseo_redirects`  SET to = replace(to, 'http',
>   'https');

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to` is [a MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), making it a poor choice of column name. (The same applies to `from`.)

Since it's a reserved word, it must be surrounded in backticks:

```
UPDATE `mytable_rsseo_redirects` SET `to` = REPLACE(`to`, 'http', 'https');
```

Comment: Oh Thanks, Great, Unfortunately the developer has named table column by to. Anyhow thanks - it works. Just a more thing if i try to find entire database and replace http with https - this is the code - UPDATE t
     set url = REPLACE(url, 'http:', 'https:')
     WHERE url like 'http:%';

Comment: Here update T - here t means table name. Is there way to scan the entire database and replace http with https

Comment: @Ruchika It's technically possible, but likely to be more effort than it's worth.